# How to handle time or memory limit error creating dictionary from user input in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, memory

I am trying to solve the problem in programming HW. User inputs names or first letters of names. The more name is repeated, the more friends a person has. The program should output a person with the biggest amount of friends (if there are people with the same number of friends, any of them can be an output). The word "END" in input should not be counted. The length of user input is not specified but task says this:

**"Please process 50,000 friends or less within 6 seconds. If you do O (n ^ 2) processing using list without using dict, it may be judged wrong answer exceeding the time limit?".**

I wrote a program to create a dictionary directly from user input and output the maximum key - value pair.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

friendships = {}
count = 0

while True:
    try:
    names = input()

    if names != 'END':

        if not friendships.get(names):
             friendships[names] = 1
        else:
            friendships[names] += 1 

    if names == '':
        break

except EOFError:
    print('ERROR')

max_key = max(friendships, key = friendships.get)
print(max_key, friendships[max_key])
```

**The automatic grader keeps on showing [ERROR: time limit exceeded or memory limit exceeded (I can't tell which)]. How can I specify that "50000 friends or less should be processed within 6 seconds"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indentation bugs and an infinite loop. You should probably also specify that you want `python3`. Also, install the exception handler before the loop instead of reinstalling it in every iteration. Use `pylint` to get some valuable hints.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

'''
friendship program
'''

def main():
    '''
    a func
    '''
    friendships = {}

    try:
        while True:
            name = input()

            if name not in ['END', '']:
                if name not in friendships:
                    friendships[name] = 1
                else:
                    friendships[name] += 1
            else:
                break

    except EOFError as ex:
        print('ERROR ' + str(ex))

    max_key = max(friendships, key=friendships.get)
    print(max_key, friendships[max_key])

main()
```

While the above should not have any problem processing 50000 names in 6 seconds, you could try doing the same in another language (if you don't have to use python that is) and see if that helps. A C++ example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned long> friends;
    std::string name;
    while(std::cin >> name) {
        if(name == "END" || name.size() == 0) break;
        ++friends[name];
    }
    auto max_it = std::max_element(
        friends.begin(), friends.end(),
        [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a.second < b.second; });

    std::cout << max_it->first << " " << max_it->second << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ted, thanks so much! It worked and I understood the mistakes in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

To tell if it's your memory that's being maxed out, use the `memory_profiler` library. You can use the `@profile` decorator, which will output memory usage per line to your stdout.

I don't think you can even make a for loop run from 1 to 50000 in 6 seconds, but a good approach to start would be to lookup a dictonary for the given input name and increment if the lookup succeeds, else, append a KV pair.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify how long something is going to take, merely code it as best you can, and see. Python doesn't really come with facilities for limiting time or memory usage, either. I suspect this grading tool uses come kind of container.

But I *can* see one issue:

```
names = input()
```

Anyone would struggle to input 50,000 names in six seconds! Even if you could, does the grader allow interactive input?

Instead, you should pre-create the friend lists, probably just as a text file, and read them in.

Comment: I don't know how or when your code will run, so I don't know. Are you able to upload multiple files?